# How to scroll page on multiple ID in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

Please check what i did yet http://jsfiddle.net/dUVmh/1/ .

**About the animation i want to achieve is that:**

When you first scroll down the page then window scroll to  **#green** DIV. After that if you again scroll down window scroll to  **#yellow** DIV & same at the time of scrollup (fom #yellow to #green).

**About the issue:**
You can see the animation it's stuck on **#green** DIV.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#green').offset().top }, 1000);
    }
    else if($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#yellow').offset().top }, 1000);
    }
    else{
         $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#red').offset().top }, 1000);
    }

});
```

I didn't have much experience in JS.

Thanks i advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a fun problem to work on.

This solution places the divs into an array, and remembers the array index of the element that was last scrolled to.  Once a scroll event is triggered it checks to see if the new scrollTop is above or below the current divs top offset and moves to the next or previous div in the array accordingly.

This solution allows you to have many divs.  I tried to remove the flickering you get when you scroll to fast, but the only way to do that I believe would be to disable the scrollbars during animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/dUVmh/35/

```
$(function() {
    var divs = [],
        body = $('body, html'),
        currentDiv = 0,
        timeout;

    $('div').each(function() {
        divs.push($(this));
    });

    // we only need to capture the first scroll event triggered and then
    // add another listener once we have done our animation
    var scrollListen = function() {
        $(window).one('scroll', function() {
            doScroll($(this).scrollTop());
        });
    };

    // Without the timeout, the scroll event would be triggered again too soon
    var scrollEnd = function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            scrollListen();
        }, 10);
    };

    // checks if the scroll direction was up and down and animates
    // the body scrollTop to the next or previous div
    var doScroll = function(scrollTop) {
        var direction = scrollTop - divs[currentDiv].offset().top;

        if (direction > 0 && currentDiv + 1 < divs.length) {
            nextDiv = currentDiv + 1;
        } else if (currentDiv - 1 > -1) {
            nextDiv = currentDiv - 1;
        }

        if (currentDiv === nextDiv) {
            scrollEnd();
        }

        body.animate({
            scrollTop: divs[nextDiv].offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
            currentDiv = nextDiv;
            scrollEnd();
        });
    };

    scrollListen();
});
```

**Edit**:  Firefox scrollTop required to be changed on html and not body.  Also fixed a problem with firefox calling scrollListen more than once at a time.

Comment: @sandeep Sorry didn't test it in firefox.  It works fine now.

Comment: Thanks for you answer & efforts :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `$(window).scroll(function())` gets called over and over again when scrolling through the `ScrollTop` animation with jQuery.

Here is a possible solution that checks if it is currently scrolling or not and only executes the `ScrollTop` animation once.

http://jsfiddle.net/dUVmh/29/

Side note: It might be a good idea to check which direction the user is scrolling (up or down) and depending on that scroll to the next div to the top or to the down.
You can check that be saving the last scrollTop position and comparing it with the current one.

**UPDATE:** Here's a solution that takes the scroll direction into account: http://jsfiddle.net/dUVmh/36/

Comment: thanks for your answer but in your solution after srcolldown the page i am enable to scrollup